# AngularJS: watch element visibility

Tags: angularjs

I have an element inside my body which is invisible. I want to trigger a function when it become visible. What is the best practice for this?

here is a [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/gBq3M2qHvEjLaGRrRGJO/preview) to a sample work. In this piece of code, the window should scroll to the '#hiddenObj' div by clicking on the button. but the first click, just the div become visible and the second time the window scrolls.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

ng-hide=false effectively adds 'display:none' to the element which means the element would not have any position to scroll to in the DOM.

So just set a $watch on the visible state of the element as below

```
var scrollElement = "#hiddenObj";
$scope.$watch(function() { return angular.element(scrollElement).is(':visible') }, function() {
    scrollTo(scrollElement);
});
```

see http://plnkr.co/edit/BGBygAWdwU6zv7anx3qO?p=preview

Comment: I do not want to hidden obj take up place, I want something like $watch on element, when ng-hide="true" the window scroll to the object.

Comment: This approach is not working for my case. I have Bootstrap tabbed form, and I am watching the style attribute 'display' of the last tab which has a canvas. If the value of 'display' changes from 'none' to 'block' then I want to trigger resize event to redraw the canvas living inside this tab. I think I need to call $scope.$digest() to make it work, but I don't know how. I am using custom directive to control the last tab and watch the display css attribute. During debug I can see that watch executing but it seems it's running too early and not function properly all the times.

Answer (score 3):

Angular adds a "ng-hide" class to an element that's hidden with ng-hide/ng-show.

One way to watch if there's been a change is to add a watcher for the element's class, and check if it contains "ng-hide".

```
scope.$watch(function() { return element.attr('class'); }, function(newValue) { 
    if (newValue.match(/ng-hide/) !== null) {
        // Element is hidden.
    }       
});
```